# MySQL / SQL Server: Excluir registros similares que tengan 1 valor NO deseado

Tags: mysql, sql-server, condiciones

Buen día.

Tengo la siguiente duda; resulta que tengo una tabla similar a esta:

```
Gestión Grupo 
75      1
75      2
76      2
77      1
```

Para algo de contexto, digamos que una gestión es una solicitud que puede ser atentida por cierta clase de grupos; para el caso, vemos que hay varias gestiones, y hay algunos grupos.

Yo simplemente quiero devolver todas aquellas gestiones en las que SÓLO aparezca el grupo 2. Vemos que la gestión 75 está siendo atentida tanto por el grupo 1 y 2; esa NO me interesa.

Sólo quiera aquellas que estén siendo atentidas por un grupo en particular, por ende, el único registro que en éste caso devolvería sería la gestión 76.

En el query:

**Select * from tablaX
where grupo = 2;**

Me devuelve el registro donde está la gestión 75 y 76, pero como ya expliqué, la 75 no me interesa porque está siendo atentida también por un grupo que no me interesa. Por supuesto no funciona aunque agregue una condición NOT IN para el grupo 1 porque aún así, seguiría cumpliendo con el que hecho de que esté para el grupo 2, devolviéndome siempre ambos registros.

¿Cómo realizo ese filtrado entonces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción es agregar la condición de que *"no exista otro registro para la misma gestión con distinto grupo"* utilizando una sub-consulta.

#### Ejemplo:

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM tabla AS A
WHERE A.grupo = 2
    AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT B.gestion 
      FROM tabla AS B
      WHERE B.gestion = A.gestion
        AND B.grupo != A.grupo
      LIMIT 1
    );
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mFhTwMDrjNA3hJYtcVzAhy/0)</kbd>

---

Otra opción seria hacer un `LEFT JOIN`

#### Ejemplo:

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM tabla AS A
    LEFT JOIN tabla AS B
        ON B.gestion = A.gestion
        AND B.grupo != A.grupo
WHERE A.grupo = 2 AND B.gestion IS NULL;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mFhTwMDrjNA3hJYtcVzAhy/1)</kbd>

Comment: Excelente, me funcionó a la perfección.

¡Muchísimas gracias!